# Can Tcp Server receive more messages at the same time?

Tags: c#, tcp

In a Tcp connection, can one Tcp Server receive two or more tcp messages at the same time from some different clients?

I have to make a small tool to manage a lot of communication from somee devices and a lot of frame exchange at the same time.

Could you give me an example?

Thanks

Comment: check out WebSocket Server

Comment: A server can have multiple connections open with multiple clients at the same time, but... TCP isn't *messages*. It's an endless stream of bytes. If you want messages, it's up to *you* to do some kind of message framing atop TCP - or to move to a higher level protocol that does do messages.

Comment: instead of "TCP server", replace that with "web server" and replace "messages" with "requests". "Can a web server receive multiple requests at the same time"? They would be pretty pointless if they couldn't. If a web server can do it built on top of TCP, so can you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as long as:

1. they are on different TCP connections, and
2. your socket reading code allows it - specifically, it won't work if you use a single reader based on `Socket.Select`, and
3. you don't add any mutex/lock/etc that prevents full concurrency over the reading